# Bipartite graph and cycle of even length

Tags: graph, bipartite

A bipartite graph  is a graph whose vertices can be divided into two disjoint sets U and V such that every edge connects a vertex in U to one in V; that is, U and V are each independent sets. Equivalently, a bipartite graph is a graph that does not contain any odd-length cycles.

Can I also say that if in a graph G all cycles are even in length, then it is bipartite?

I thought of one graph of even length cycle and it turned out to be non-bipartite.

```
     1----------2
     |          |
     |          |
     |          |
     |          |
     3----------4
```

Comment: This graph is bipartite - U = (1, 4}, V = {2, 3}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If in a graph G all cycles are even in length, then it is bipartite.

Apply BFS algorithm to graph G. It divides vertices of G into layers. Set U consists of vertices from odd layers, V of vertices from even layers. Let's assume (by contradiction) that there exists edge *e* that connects some two vertices *x, y* from U. Let *r* be the root of tree determined by BFS algorithm. Then path from *x* to *r*, from *r* to *y*, and edge *e* are cycle of odd length - that's contradiction as graph G doesn't contain odd-length cycles. (same with set V).